# Nginx redirect from / to folder and port

Tags: nginx

How to setup nginx proxy to redirect from `domain.com` port 80 to `domain.com:/client` port 8080 with `domain.com` URL in a browser? I tried the next config:

```
# cat MySite.conf 

server {
        server_name www.domain.com domain.com;
        listen  8080;
        return 301 $scheme://domain.com/folder;

}

server {
        server_name domain.com;
        listen 80;

    location /folder {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503; 
        proxy_pass http://10.10.1.2:8080/folder;
            }
}
```

When I open `domain.com/folder` everything works fine, but when I tried `domain.com` in my browser I got nginx welcome screen.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you are not showing full nginx configuration. it might be hard for us to understand the config.

Answer (score 0):

> location directives cover requests for specific files and folders, such as http://example.com/blog/. Here are some examples:

- location / { }
- location /images/ { }
- location /blog/ { }
- location /planet/ { }
- location /planet/blog/ { }

so I assume if you try **location / {}** instead of **location /folder {}** it would work